# how to show updown log event on aruba switch port

Tags: switch, aruba

I'm trying to check the event logs on a port that keeps flapping on aruba switch. is there a similar cli command like from cisco switch im using show log | i UPDOWN.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `show log | i ports:` or more specifically `show log | i port .* is now`.